# Mysql Error on joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a query using (and joining) three tables, but I have an error that i cannot understand on the query I'm doing. I'm using IF, AS and IN in the query statement. This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, friends.recipient, friends.sender, message.sender, message.recipient, message.date, message.time
FROM users 
JOIN friends
    ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
JOIN message 
    ON (users.id = message.recipient OR users.id = message.sender)
WHERE 75 IN (friends.sender,friends.recipient) 
    OR friends.status = 1 IF(message.recipient = 75, 'message.recieved', 'message.sent') AS message.direction 
 FROM message WHERE message.recipient IN (75, 129) AND sender IN (75, 129)
```

And this is the line causing the error:

> IF(message.recipient = 75, 'message.recieved', 'message.sent') AS
>   message.direction

Comment: You're missing an `AND` or an `OR` operator before the `IF`. And as mentioned the second `FROM` is also not valid at this place.

Comment: Tried both of those, AND just moves the error further down. and I removed FROM does nothing, and I do realise that I don't need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you wrote two query separately:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname,
friends.recipient, friends.sender, message.sender,
message.recipient, message.date, message.time
FROM users 
JOIN friends
ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
JOIN message 
ON (users.id = message.recipient OR users.id = message.sender)
WHERE 75 IN (friends.sender,friends.recipient) 
OR friends.status = 1
```

---

```
SELECT  IF(message.recipient = 75, 'message.recieved',
'message.sent') AS message.direction FROM message WHERE
message.recipient IN (75, 129) AND sender IN (75, 129)
```

Do it together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, friends.recipient, friends.sender, message.sender, message.recipient, message.date, message.time ,  IF(message.recipient = 75, 'message.recieved', 'message.sent') AS message.direction
FROM users 
JOIN friends
    ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
JOIN message 
    ON (users.id = message.recipient OR users.id = message.sender)
WHERE ( 75 IN (friends.sender,friends.recipient) 
    OR friends.status = 1 )
    AND message.recipient IN (75, 129) 
    AND message.sender IN (75, 129)
```

Comment: Thats great! Thank you very much! 
You where right I did have a 1st query which was joining two tables and I tried adding a 2nd query